# How do i store users in Http sessions with java spring boot and JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I will be glad to know how do i store a user in http session after his login using spring boot.

basicly i want to store the entity "Teacher" in my session to control the pages that the user can access if he is logged in or not.

This is my entity that i want to store in http session:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 254)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 254, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 254, unique = true)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
    private List<Scheduling> schedulings = new ArrayList<>();
```

and this is my login verifier:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/validateLogin")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> validateLogin(@RequestBody Map<String, String> user) {
        try {
            Teacher t = teacherRepository.findUser(user.get("name"), user.get("email"));
            if (t != null && encoder.matches(user.get("password"), t.getPassword())) {
                //
                //I WANT TO STORE THE ENTITY HERE BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW
                //
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                        .body(Map.of("result", "ok", "details", "login approved"));
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .body(Map.of("result", "error", "details", "login denied"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body(Map.of("result", "error", "details", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

and i want verify if the user is logged here:

```
@GetMapping("/mainPage")
    public String mainPage() {
        //
        //IF USER IN HTTP SESSION{
        //
        return "mainPage";
        //ELSE RETURN YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN!
    }
```

Comment: Instead of trying to do this all manually (writing code to let users log in, adding lots of checks if the user is allowed to do this or that) this might be a good idea to learn [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can modify `validateLogin` like

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/validateLogin")
        public ResponseEntity<Object> validateLogin(@RequestBody Map<String, String> user,HttpServletRequest request) {
            try {
                Teacher t = teacherRepository.findUser(user.get("name"), user.get("email"));
                if (t != null && encoder.matches(user.get("password"), t.getPassword())) {
                    //
                    //I WANT TO STORE THE ENTITY HERE BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW
                    //store the object in session
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("teacher", t);
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                            .body(Map.of("result", "ok", "details", "login approved"));
                } else {
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                            .body(Map.of("result", "error", "details", "login denied"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                        .body(Map.of("result", "error", "details", e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
```

and `mainPage` like

```
@GetMapping("/mainPage")
    public String mainPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //
        //IF USER IN HTTP SESSION{
        //
    if(request.getSession()!=null){
//access from session
         Teacher t=(Teacher)request.getSession().getAttribute("teacher");
//your logic to validate can come here
    }

        return "mainPage";
        //ELSE RETURN YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN!
    }
```